# Ruby Rspec AXLSX unit testing error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, rspec, axlsx

Here is my code.

```
wb = xlsx_package.workbook
wb.add_worksheet(name: 'my_work_sheet') do |sheet|
   sheet.add_row ['first row']
end
```

I have written unit test for above code.
Here is it:

```
it 'should write data in file' do
    workbook = double('Workbook')
    worksheet = double('Worksheet')

    expect(xlsx_package).to receive(:workbook).and_return(workbook)
    expect(workbook).to receive(:add_worksheet).with(name: 'my_work_sheet').and_return(worksheet)
    expect(worksheet).to receive(:add_row).with(['first row'])
end
```

I am getting error **'xlsx_package'** not found

Comment: I am getting the same issue.

Comment: Is it the `view` test? Can you provide the full info for your test at least the things which it related to(before/let/describe blocks)?

Comment: There are no before/after/let statements. describe block is as:                                       

describe 'report.xlsx.axlsx' do

end

actual file name is 'report.xlsx.axlsx'

Answer (score 2):

Here's how `xlsx_package` is assigned:

```
def self.call(template)
  "xlsx_author = defined?(xlsx_author).nil? ? nil : xlsx_author;\n" +
  "xlsx_created_at = defined?(xlsx_created_at).nil? ? nil : xlsx_created_at;\n" +
  "xlsx_use_shared_strings = defined?(xlsx_use_shared_strings).nil? ? nil : xlsx_use_shared_strings;\n" +
  "xlsx_package = Axlsx::Package.new(\n" +
    ":author => xlsx_author,\n" +
    ":created_at => xlsx_created_at,\n" +
    ":use_shared_strings => xlsx_use_shared_strings\n" +
    ");\n" +
  template.source +
  ";\nxlsx_package.to_stream.string;"
end
```

https://github.com/straydogstudio/axlsx_rails/blob/afdcf7266b91f3d70c640209702257a635afddc4/lib/axlsx_rails/template_handler.rb#L13

As you can see you can't stub this, but you can change your test a bit:

```
it 'should write data in file' do
  workbook = double('Workbook')
  worksheet = double('Worksheet')
  xlsx_package = double('Package', workbook: workbook)

  expect(Axlsx::Package).to receive(:new).and_return(xlsx_package)

  expect(xlsx_package).to receive(:workbook).and_return(workbook)
  expect(workbook).to receive(:add_worksheet).with(name: 'my_work_sheet').and_return(worksheet)
  expect(worksheet).to receive(:add_row).with(['first row'])
end
```

I can't give you the full example because you haven't posted your view template. 
You also need to understand how the rendering works with the view tests, because your test is still invalid.